# Is writing, "Dear pre-school teachers, don't teach write A for Apple, first?" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

Is writing, "Dear pre-school teachers, don't teach write A for Apple, first?" correct?

Or, it should be...

Dear pre-school teachers, don't teach to write A for Apple, first?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb "write" would need a "to infinitive".

But we normally use this construction with an explicit subject for the infinitive verb

> Don't teach your pupils to write "A for apple".

It would, perhaps, be better not to use "write" at all, and just say

> Don't teach, "A for apple".

Comment: Thank you. I get that.